# PySpark - Struggling to arrange the data by a specific format

Tags: pyspark

I am working on outputting total deduplicated counts from a pre-aggregated frame as follows.

I currently have a data frame that displays like so. It's the initial structure and the point that I have gotten to by filtering out unneeded columns.

| ID | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Grape |
| 101 | Flower |
| 102 | Bee |
| 103 | Peach |
| 105 | Flower |

We can see from the example above that 101 is found in both Grape and Flower. I would like to arrange the format so that the distinct string values from the "Source" column become their own sources, as from there I can perform a groupBy for a specific arrangement of yes's and no's as so.

| ID | Grape | Flower | Bee | Peach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| 102 | No | No | Yes | No |
| 103 | No | No | No | Yes |

I agree that creating this manually via the above example is a good fit, but I am working with +100m rows and need something more susinct.

What I've extracted so far is a list of distinct Source values and arranged them into a list:

```
dedupeTableColumnNames = dedupeTable.select('SOURCE').distinct().collect()
dedupeTableColumnNamesCleaned = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", str(dedupeTableColumnNames))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a pivot :

```py
df.groupBy("id").pivot("source").count().show()
+---+------+------+------+------+                                               
| id|Bee   |Flower|Grape |Peach |
+---+------+------+------+------+
|103|  null|  null|  null|     1|
|105|  null|     1|  null|  null|
|101|  null|     1|     1|  null|
|102|     1|  null|  null|  null|
+---+------+------+------+------+
```